# Not supported exception thrown while casting in to object in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to cast the filtered records to object. The not supported exception throws only when Entity Framework is used.

This code snippet is used in my application

```
var filteredRecords = this.SourceCollection.AsQueryable();
IEnumerable<object> distinctRecords = null;
distinctRecords = filteredRecords.Cast<object>().Select(x => provider.GetValue(x, colName)).Distinct();
```

Some of the sites suggested to use `.ToList` instead of `.Cast`, but using `.ToList` will affect performance. Please suggest any other better way.

Comment: Can you provide more details of the exception that is thrown?

Comment: Does replacing `.Cast<object>()` with `.AsEnumerable()` help?

Comment: Not Supported exception .Unable to cast the type 'Order_detail' to type 'object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: the answer below (suggesting you to use `IEnumerable`) should be fine, you should check out that and leave some comment if it does not suit you (don't forget to give some reason). BTW I think that is the easiest way. We cannot cast each entity to object easily (I've done something like this but had to use an Expression tree - which is very complicated).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot cast to an object here is because the query is still being constructed and the results have not been enumerated yet. Calling the `ToList` extension will force the query to execute, after which you will be able to cast the results to an object.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but you might try declaring `distinctRecords` as a non-generic `IEnumerable` instead:

```
IEnumerable distinctRecords = filteredRecords.Select(x => provider.GetValue(x, colName));
```

Calling `Select` will also enumerate the results, so you could just cast the results to an object after that.